# What's the significance of Seasons in Star Trek Online?

Tags: star-trek-online

I just got started playing Star Trek Online last night.  I've now realized that "Season 6" is already on its way.  What exactly does this mean?

Are the "Seasons" just milestones in this MMO's life, like major software version numbers?  Or do they represent more significant changes in the environment and story?

Most particularly, am I missing anything important to the story or game experience by having not been around for Seasons 1-4 and most of 5?  If so, is there any way to "catch up" like one would with a regular TV show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Updates to the game are called "Seasons" and are issued to current subscribers free of charge. Season releases are versioned, with major releases offering broad changes, and minor versions that add simpler features, "Quality of Life" changes, and bug fixes."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Online#Seasons_.28Free_updates.29

Answer (score 0):

Seasons are the equivalent of expansions in the game. They are playable by all players, subscribers and free to play.

Each season usually adds at minimum the following:

- A new reputation system, therefore new items, sets
- New story-line, therefore new foes and ships
- New space or ground repeatable missions (related to reputation usually)

Compared to that, the minor version updates are more focused on bug fixing,balancing and they add a single story mission along with a new item set.